# Including partial unless specific page classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, middleman

I'm adding a unique page class to the body tag of each page via the layout.erb.  I want to include a particular partial on all but a few pages on my site. Not all pages have a class set. Currently I get a syntax error with my example below.

`<%= partial 'partials/tagline' if (array.include?(current_page.data.page_classes) || array.empty? && %w(page_home page_fourohfour page_post)) %>`

Error message: `SyntaxError at /
layouts/layout.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end ...e page_fourohfour page_post)) ).to_s; @_out_buf << ' ... ^`

Comment: Can you post the error message being displayed?

Comment: Added to original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple option that should work is the following:

```
<% if (array.include?(current_page.data.page_classes) || array.empty? && %w(page_home page_fourohfour page_post)) %>
  <%= partial 'partials/tagline' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the function you want is render, which accepts a hash argument, and partial is one of the keys in that hash (rather than the function itself).

Try this:

```
<%= render :partial => "partials/tagline" if (array.include?(current_page.data.page_classes) || array.empty? && %w(page_home page_fourohfour page_post)) %>
```

Or simply:

```
<%= render "partials/tagline" if (array.include?(current_page.data.page_classes) || array.empty? && %w(page_home page_fourohfour page_post)) %>
```